# If field is empty in attribute table, programatically populate subsequent field with that data

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have a CSV communicating directly with a series of points and lines. The CSV is a bit problematic, however. The hardware that provides the data only provides **location** data every few rows. That is, there is an attribute table with X and Y columns whose fields are only filled only at key times. The rest is other still useful data, but location is only updated intermittently.

I have my point feature structured so that only the bottom-most (most recent) attribute row is used to display one point. Naturally I need location data for that bottom-most row, otherwise the point disappears. Currently I'm not getting it but sporadically. My CSV -> point code looks like this currently (pyshp library used):

```
        cur_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

        file_location = os.path.join(cur_dir, "data", "mycsv.csv")
        out_file = os.path.join(cur_dir, "data", "mypoint.shp")
        idd, az, y, x = [], [], [], []

        with open(file_location, 'rb') as csvfile:
            r = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','))
            reader = r[len(r) - 1:] #read only top row
            for i, row in reversed(list(enumerate(reader))): #reverse table
                idd.append(str(row[0]))
                az.append(float(row[2]))
                y.append(float(row[6]))
                x.append(float(row[7]))
                print "appended"


        w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POINT)
        w.field('ID', 'N')
        w.field('AZIMUTH', 'N', 12)
        w.field('Y', 'F', 10, 8)
        w.field('X', 'F', 10, 8)

        for j, k in enumerate(x): #write shapefile
            w.point(k, y[j])
            w.record(idd[j],az[j],y[j], k )
            print "recorded"

        w.save(out_file)
```

Here is a snippet of the CSV. You will see the chopped up columns on the right:
[image]

I have started by trying to add `if x > 0:` conditionals in various places below the multiple enumerators to possibly halt digitization until data is read, but I am given error `min() arg is an empty sequence` each time. I'm not even sure this is the right place to begin, as it would probably just put attributes out of sequence with each other. I really just need some sort of *"if X or Y field is null, populate field with prior field's data*" script.

I am using Python 2.7, developing out of QGIS 2.8 API, and running on Ubuntu 14.04,

Comment: Isn't this a just a straight Python issue?

Comment: @vince I'm not sure how to answer that. It might be?

Comment: GIS SE exists for GIS-centric questions.  If the question is about Python code accessing GIS components, it's a GIS question; if the question is about Python looping or flow of control, it's a Python question.  This question appears to be on the ragged edge between the two -- it's flow of control to access a library for GIS data, but it seems closer to a [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) question (especially considering that your program logic is using more memory than necessary by saving all the data between read and write, instead of integrating the two -- read, write, read, write).

Comment: You have a QGIS tag but no QGIS library appears to be used in the code snippet that you have presented so this looks like Python rather than GIS to me too.

Comment: @vince @polygeo I suppose my reasoning for asking this in GIS SE was that, while no QGIS library is used in this snippet of code, it does still implement `pyshp`, which is a python library for working with shapefiles. Because of this, I suspect my problem may be more familiar to a GIS coding community than a general coding community. However, I understand that this question still sits in a gray area. I'll ask elsewhere.

Comment: The fact that the output is a shapefile seems incidental to the task of persisting the last valid field in a CSV file across rows.  I urge you to restructure your program logic to { open, create, initFieldVals, loop: { read, write }, close, close} . Once you are persisting a single row at a time, change detection should be much easier (and may not require assistance, which is the whole point of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: @Vince Thanks for the advice, I'll definitely look into restructuring.